# Indent UIWebview content / Move Scrollbar back to edge of screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView to show local content in HTML. I want the content indented on each side so as to not touch the side of the screen. The problem is the content is in the UiWebView, so when I resize the webview the scroll bar sticks out (see picture below).

[image]

I'm at my wit's end trying to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the UIWebView edge to edge, then you can either inject the following CSS code, or add it directly to the files (since you say they are in the app bundle).

```
div.myContent {
    padding-right:50px;
    padding-left:50px;
}
```

You can of course change `div.myContent` to whatever you want.
This way, scroll bar stays on edge but content indents on both sides.

Comment: How do I use CSS in Objective C?